# Python save output of SQL query to Excel

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

First of all I am trying to retrieve a list of all possible databases, that works fine.

In the second part it executes a query for each database in the list. And it will give me back the name and create_Date for each database where the create_Date is equal or greater than 01-01-2020.

So when I when do 'print(row)' it gives me exaclty what I want.

But how do I write the result of the query to an Excel file? I already import pandas as pd.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'f'Server={server};'f'Database= 
{db};'f'UID={username};'f'PWD={password};')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name  FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases")
result = cursor.fetchall()
ams_sql02 = []
for row in result:
    ams_sql02.append(row[0])
    ams_sql02 = [databases.lower() for databases in ams_sql02]

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
for db in ams_sql02:
     cursor.execute(f'SELECT name, convert(varchar(10),create_date,103) as dateCreated fROM 
     sys.databases where name = \'{db}\' and create_date > \'2020-01-01 10:13:03.290\' 
     order by create_date')

      result = cursor.fetchall()
      for row in result:
          print(row)
```

Comment: So build a dataframe and write it to excel? You haven't shown your code attempt or explained any difficulties you faced. In addition to that, you're using f-strings to build your query rather than using parameterization, and using escape characters purely for the sake of not using `"` to build the query

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: To add to the previous comment, you can even use the driver and get the results in a dataframe easier with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html, then the .to_excel() method will work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put SQL query to Excel without Python? Excel works with datasources like MS SQL Server quite well.